# Limit number of item can be selected in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an issue in the following implementation. I define how many maximum items can be selected in each section in the tableview.

Let's assume user is allowed to select only **two** items in the section 0. If user tries to select the **third** one, then the **first** selected item will be deselected and third item will have **checkmark** accessory.

My following implementation cannot able to handle, it allows more than two items with all the **checkmarks**. I wonder where I am doing wrong?

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int numberOfItemsSelected = [[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary valueForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexPath.section]] intValue];

    if(((ComboItem*)comboItemsArray[indexPath.section]).itemNumberEachCombo == numberOfItemsSelected)
    {
        NSIndexPath *oldIndex = [self.comboTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self.comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self.comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return indexPath;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self selectedItem:self.comboTableView];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self selectedItem:self.comboTableView];
}

- (void)selectedItem: (UITableView *)tableView {
    selectedRowsInSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray <NSIndexPath*> *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        NSString *sectionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",indexpath.section];
        NSInteger numberOfSelectedRows = [[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey: sectionKey] integerValue];
        numberOfSelectedRows++;
        [selectedRowsInSectionDictionary setObject:@(numberOfSelectedRows) forKey: sectionKey];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    if([[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =  ((ComboItem*)comboItemsArray[indexPath.section]).allComboItems[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: add cellForRowAtindexpath method .

Comment: I have just included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** (after trying it on my sample project)

Implementation of `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method looks incorrect to me. Also,  `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns the first index-path object in the array of row selections; hence returning the first selected index of 0th section always.

This is the implementation after **removing** method -`(void)selectedItem: (UITableView *)tableView` and selectedRowsInSectionDictionary variable  and **adding** a new NSMutable dictionary variable for maintaining array of selected index paths, `selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        int numberOfItemsSelected = [[selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)] count];

        if(((ComboItem*)comboItemsArray[indexPath.section]).itemNumberEachCombo == numberOfItemsSelected)
        {
            NSIndexPath *oldIndex = [[selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)] firstObject];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex animated:NO];
            [self tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex];
        }
         return indexPath;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
    {
        [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [self selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [comboTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [self deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    - (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
        NSMutableArray* array = [selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)];
        if(array){
            [array addObject:indexPath];
        } else {
            array = [NSMutableArray array];
            [array addObject:indexPath];
            [selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary setObject:array forKey:@(indexPath.section)];
        }
    }

    - (void)deselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
        NSMutableArray* array = [selectedIndexPathsInSectionDictionary objectForKey:@(indexPath.section)];
        [array removeObject:indexPath];
    }
```

[image]

[github link](https://github.com/puneet25/MultipleSelectionTableView) of the sample project

Comment: For some reasons, whenever the second section item reaches the maximum number, it also deselecting the first section's items. It is weird. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, I got it, indexPathForSelectedRow always returns the first index-path object in the array of row selections; hence returning the first selected index of 0th section always, making the logic flawed. better would be to maintain a dictionary of selected indexpaths with key being section and array of indexpaths as value

Comment: Could you please add into your answer? I have already had this logic ( keep track of selected indexPath for each section in the dictionary,  - `(void)selectedItem: (UITableView *)tableView` but how would I use it?

Comment: @hotspring: Above implementation is working in my sample project

Comment: I am writing you in my bed, I am going to check your code first thing in the morning. I have just upvoted, once I check then I will mark as an answer. I would be fantastic if you upload your sample project on github and link it. That would be useful for others as well.

Comment: Any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125520/clicked-header-section-is-scroll-to-top